# Modify Google Analytics custom dimensions to track the_modified_author like author?

Tags: google-analytics

This code is working to track author pageviews on Analytics. However, I would like to track pageviews for posts by the_modified_author.

Can anyone please adapt the code for this? Thanks for any efforts.

If anyone is able to do it, I just need to track Author, the_modified_author, and categories for a WordPress blog. If someone from the community could edit this code (or provide a different one), in addition to my real thanks and appreciation, I would offer something from their wishlist up to around $20.

Added to functions.php

```
function google_load_file() {
        $this_post = get_queried_object();
        $author_id = $this_post->post_author;
        $name = get_the_author_meta('display_name', $author_id);


        wp_enqueue_script( 'author-tracking', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/google.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
        wp_localize_script( 'author-tracking', 'author', array( 'name' => $name ) );

}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'google_load_file' );
```

A js file made for this purpose

```
   (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-12345678-3', 'domain.com');
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
ga('set', 'dimension1', author.name );
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use in your google_load_file function the [get_the_modified_author()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_modified_author) function it will return the display name of the author that last modified the post. At least that's the description for the function:

> Retrieve the author who last edited the current post.
>
> Return values: The author's display name.

```
function google_load_file() {
$this_post = get_queried_object();        
$name = get_the_modified_author();

wp_enqueue_script( 'author-tracking', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . /js/google.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
        wp_localize_script( 'author-tracking', 'author', array( 'name' => $name ) );
}
```

I assume this will only in templates for single posts.

Comment: Thank you very much, Eike Pierstorff.  Do you know if I can just add your lines into my existing (to track both), or should I copy the code I'm using, modify it according to your lines, and have both in sequence in the file?

Comment: change the two lines: $author_id = $this_post->post_author;  $name = get_the_author_meta('display_name', $author_id); for the one line $name = get_the_modified_author();. according to the Wordpress documentation this should give you the result you want.

Comment: In order to track both variables (author and the_modified_author, though?

Comment: If anyone is able to do it, I just need to track Author, the_modified_author, and categories for a WordPress blog. If someone from the community could edit this code (or provide a different one), in addition to my real thanks and appreciation, I would offer something from their wishlist up to around $20.